# Active Data between Dates in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a data in which new records are created on a regular basis.
Following are the fields of data: Id, Name, createdOn, Expiry.

I need to create a dashboard which shows the data between selected start date and end date. I created two date parameters start and end. selected `cnt(id)` on rows and `month(createdOn)` date on columns.

I got the data a newly created records correctly, but I want count of unexpired records in the selected range.

For example:

```
+-----+--------+-------------+------------+
| id  |  name  |  createdOn  |   expiry   |
+-----+--------+-------------+------------+
|  1  |  a     |  1/1/2015   |  3/2/2015  |
|  2  |  b     |  2/1/2015   |  2/20/2015 |
|  3  |  c     |  1/10/2015  |  2/1/2015  |
|  4  |  d     |  1/20/2015  |  2/15/2015 |
+-----+--------+-------------+------------+
```

For this data, the report should show count of records month wise in the selected range.

**Expected**

- Jan : 3
- Feb : 4
- Mar : 1

**Actual**

- Jan : 3
- Feb : 1
- Mar : 0

Comment: Did you ever determine a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I believe tableau is considering the date format as DD/MM/YYYY and you are considering the date format as MM/DD/YYYY.

Try to change the date format using "Format" options and do count of records.

Let me know if there is any luck. :)

Thanks,
Aish.